# Array.of() vs new Array()

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
console.log(Array.of('a','b','c'))

console.log(new Array('a','b','c'))
```

What is the difference between them and which one is best to use?

Comment: `Array.of` is unsupported in IE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Array#of` documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

> The difference between `Array.of()` and the `Array` constructor is in the
>   handling of integer arguments: `Array.of(7)` creates an array with a
>   single element, 7, whereas `Array(7)` creates an empty array with a
>   length property of 7 (Note: this implies an array of 7 empty slots,
>   not slots with actual undefined values).

Answer (score 2):

The [first result of google](https://www.google.com/search?q=array.of%20js&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) brings the answer [right away](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

> The difference between `Array.of()` and the Array constructor is in the
>   handling of integer arguments: `Array.of(7)` creates an array with a
>   single element, 7, whereas `Array(7)` creates an empty array with a
>   length property of 7 (Note: this implies an array of 7 empty slots,
>   not slots with actual undefined values).

Comment: Yes. I did it. But my question is  comparison with `new Array()`.

Comment: ... and this snippet answers about `new Array`

Comment: "... the Array constructor ..." means `new Array()`

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you pass an int as parameter

```
Array.of(2)
```

creates the array `[2]`

```
new Array(2)
```

creates the array `[empty x 2]`

Comment: But what about if I pass the values which is mentioned in my question

Comment: With parameters that are not int, there is no difference between Array.of and new Array